# Simple int to NSString conversion as in Java?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, int

Is there any simple way how to initialize String in Objective-C with int such as in Java:

```
String myStr = 42 + "";
```

or I have to do

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", 42];
```

everytime?

Comment: I always do it with your second idea... but if that is too much for you, you could create a helper method for that.

Comment: Nah, the thing is, I always have to call this static method from NSString class, I was wondering if there is faster way, I always forget that @"%d"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also use the `NSNumber` class for that:

```
NSNumber *number = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInteger: val];
NSString *string = [number stringValue];
```

Perhaps not shorter, but it could be eventually faster.
Also you could create as said a helper method, than you wouldn't have to use more code than with the `stringWithFormat:` method.

Comment: I like this workaround, are you sure about the speed? It is better in a way that I don't need that @"%d" which I always Google, bcs I just forget which letter it is I put there...:D

Comment: No I don't know if it is faster, you could benchmark it if you want... :)

Comment: it should be slower since it's allocating two objects instead of one. But the difference would be so miniscule it shouldn't matter.

Comment: Perhaps it would nearly same fast as the other possibility, but the advantage here is that you don't have to mind about signed, unsigned numbers etc. and their stringWithFormat "representation char" (%d, etc)

Comment: Can somebody prove this way is faster?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you have to do

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", 42];
```

for Integer to string conversion.

Answer (score 0):

Using a constant, like 42 in your example, you can write

```
NSString *myString = @"42";
```

Using a variable or expression, you can write

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", myValue];
```